# Automatically kill specific process by name whenever it runs again ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, process, kill

I somehow need a script to automatically kill a process by it's name on ubuntu, whenever that process runs again. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you sure you are asking the right question? What about "Stop a program from starting"?

Comment: Almost, "Whenever it starts, kill it". if there is way to just make not to run, that is going to be more great.

Comment: What is the process and what version of Ubuntu. Really you should be able to stop any process from automatically starting - its.a matter of knowing where to look.  Also, killing some processes will cause them to immediately restart consuming most of your cpu.

Comment: If you give a few details (name of process, Ubuntu version) this should be quite easy to answer.

Comment: process is prometheus, ubuntu server 18.04. I was looking for process not to start automatically, I really couldn't figure out. I've found other way to shut down, but I just want to just make not to run.

Comment: perhaps `sudo systemctl disable prometheus`? or do you not have root? that said, disabling a monitoring engine is somewhat suspicious. why do you want to ?

Comment: I have root, prometheus service doesn't exist. This is running by the function of other program, but there is no way to disable it, so want to kill it.

Comment: Is it being run from the same _path_ every time (e.g. /usr/bin/prometheus)?

Comment: yes, and it is on docker.